# When is asking a duplicate ok?

Tags: support, duplicates

This question: [Kinetic theory derivation of viscosity of a gas](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155795/kinetic-theory-derivation-of-viscosity-of-a-gas) has an accepted answer. That answer, however, does not contain the amount of detail that I want for a specific part of the question. I have (in the recent past) placed a bounty on the question asking for more detail, however no other answers where forthcoming. I am guessing that if I re-asked the part of the question I require, it would rather quickly be closed as a duplicate.

So my questions is this:

Are there any situations where a duplicate is ok, and if so does my above case fall into one of these situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the bounty asking for an extension/explanation of part of the question did not work, I think it should be okay to post a new question on that extensions/explanation you want. *But* you will need to frame it in such a way that you specify exactly *why* it is different from the older one. For example, saying something like,

> This other question (link as well) asks why X is possible, but the answer doesn't describe feature Y that I think is partly responsible or otherwise important. Could someone explain if this feature Y performs the function as I expressed here?

would go a lot further than simply asking the same thing again.

Comment: Yep, I endorse this (for whatever it's worth), though I'd point out that the new question should add something to what the original question asks. The mere fact that the existing answers don't cover what you want to know doesn't keep it from being a duplicate.

Comment: @DavidZ Just to let you know I have added a question (although I posted it just before your comment I do think it satisfies what you have said) http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/223710/